# Bash array ignores if conditions given

Tags: arrays, bash, file

I'm reading a file like

```
state 100 NULL
operator 2 0 3 NULL
```

and I want to parse it to an array line wise to check it for certain conditions
so what i actual do is:

```
#!/bin/bash
fileLines=$(cat file)
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $fileLines
do
    IFS=$' ' read -r -a lineArray <<< $line 
    echo ${lineArray[@]}
    if [[ ${lineArray["state"]} ]] ; 
    then
       echo "hit"
    fi
done
```

but it unfortunately comes back with the output

```
state 100 NULL
hit
operator 2 0 3 NULL
hit
```

even if I check for equality by using

```
if [[ ${lineArray[0]} == "state" ]] ;
```

it is still ignoring the condition I gave to the script. Is there a better way to check my array for conditions?

Comment: `if [[ ${lineArray[0]} == "state" ]] ;` works for me

Comment: @doubleDown your right. Seems that I made a mistake on this statement earlier. But the original code is not working.
In fact, that i have to add some more conditions i prefer the code of fedorqui, it's very good readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you check it like this?

```
[[ "$line" == *"stat"*  ]] && echo yes
```

#### Test

```
$ t="operator 2 0 3 NULL"
$ [[ "$t" == *"stat"*  ]] && echo yes
$

$ t="stat 100 NULL"
$ [[ "$t" == *"stat"*  ]] && echo yes
yes
```

Comment: To go along with this answer, you don't need to read the entire file into memory at once; just read it line-by-line: `while read -r line; do ...; done < file`.

Comment: So the `-r` makes it load just one line each time instead of the entire file?

Comment: `read` always just reads one line; the `-r` simply tells `read` not to process backslashes in the input specially.

Comment: Ah, right, so your proposal is to use `while read` instead of the `for line in` in the OP. Good one.

Answer (score 1):

The array is **indexed by integers**, and it looks like any non-integer strings are coerced to zero, so `${lineArray["state"]}` will always return `${lineArray[0]}`. `man bash` is rather vague on the subject:

> Referencing
>          an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to  referencing  the
>          array with a subscript of 0.

Based on the last line of code you posted, it's unclear what you actually are trying to accomplish with this code.